# eSATA ST500VT000 HD didn't working in Ubuntu 22.04, but it is OK using Ubunru 16.04

Tags: drivers, mount, hard-drive, sata

It was possible use eSAT HD using Ubuntu 16.04, and I received those messages:

[65413.223368] ata5: exception Emask 0x10 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x4040000 action 0xe frozen
[65413.223376] ata5: irq_stat 0x00000040, connection status changed
[65413.223383] ata5: SError: { CommWake DevExch }
[65413.223393] ata5: hard resetting link
[65415.567871] ata5: SATA link up 3.0 Gbps (SStatus 123 SControl 300)
[65415.860097] ata5.00: ATA-8: ST500VT000-1DK142, 0001SDC1, max UDMA/133
[65415.860105] ata5.00: 976773168 sectors, multi 0: LBA48 NCQ (depth 31/32)
[65415.899181] ata5.00: configured for UDMA/133
[65415.899199] ata5: EH complete
[65415.899513] scsi 4:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      ST500VT000-1DK14 SDC1 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
[65415.900609] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] 976773168 512-byte logical blocks: (500 GB/466 GiB)
[65415.900620] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] 4096-byte physical blocks
[65415.900645] sd 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[65415.900757] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[65415.900766] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
[65415.900811] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[65415.921045]  sdb: sdb1
[65415.921551] sd 4:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk

But when I connect this same eSATA HD using Ubuntu 22.04 I didn't see any message, look like that kernel didn't recognize this HD.

Is possible someone help me in this topic?

Thanks in advance.

My best regards,